# How to assert validation failure if there are extra fields in nodejs and mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Following is my schema definition:

```
var mongoose     = require('mongoose');
var Schema       = mongoose.Schema;

var StudentSchema   = new Schema({
    name: String,
    family: String
}, {strict: 'throw' });

module.exports = mongoose.model('Student', StudentSchema);
```

Now while making a POST call, if I add extra fields other than `name` and `family`, the extra fields are correctly ignored, but the document still persists in mongodb. How do I throw validation error in such cases?

Controller code:

```
try {
        bird.save(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                res.statusCode = 404;
                return res.send({message: err});
            }

            res.json({message: 'Student created!'});
        });
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log("error");
        callback(e);
    }
```

If I pass the following payload, it persists in mongoDB:

```
{
    "name": "name1",
    "family": "family1",
    "dummy": "dummy"
}
```

Ideally, since it has an extra field `dummy`, I want to throw validation error.

Comment: @JohnnyHK: I have updated the question with the required details.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the [`strict`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict) option of the schema to `'throw'` to cause an exception to be thrown when fields outside of what's defined in the schema are present when creating a new document:

```
var StudentSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    family: String
}, { strict: 'throw' });
```

But it's an exception, not a validation error, so you need to use try / catch to handle it:

```
try {
    Student.create(req.body, callback);
}
catch (e) {
    callback(e);
}
```

Comment: This is not working. Seems like it is not working with latest version of Mongoose:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28311205/mongoose-throws-field-is-not-in-schema-error-when-defining-a-field-twice

Comment: I am also using Mongoose 4.5.3. But it is not throwing exception. It is storing in MongoDB.

Comment: Can you update your question with the code that you're now using?

Comment: @Vraj You should get the exception when calling `new Student(req.body)` if you're not using `create`. Can you show that code as well?

Answer (score 0):

you can use  [pre-save validation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save), but mongoose ignores the extra fields

you can also do :

```
var student = new Student({

                  name:req.body.name,
                  family:req.body.family 

                  });

student.save(callback);
```

Comment: I want throw a validation error in case of extra fields. How is this going to help? I know Mongoose ignores extra fields